# Eloquent model delegate to related model

Tags: laravel, inheritance, eloquent

I currently have two models: `A`→`hasOne`→`B`

`B` represent a base class and `A` is one of its extending classes, so sometimes I want to access `B` attributes/methods trough `A` as if it were its own.

An example would be the classic `BaseMonster`-`SpecificMonster` video game use case: my `BaseMonster` model has some attributes like color, etc. and some method like walk, etc., and I would like to access those attributes and methods from my `SpecificMonster` model.

How can I do that?

I looked into `DelegatesToResource` trait to get some hint/clue but I think it is too bounded/related to API calls and stuff.
I'm looking at how hooking into the `__get` magic method of my `A` model without breaking any of Eloquent existing logic, but without luck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's what I came out with:

- For attributes it is a basic check on the attribute existence.
  It rely on the extending model to not have attributes in common with the base model, so I just check for `null` value since if the attribute doesn't exists neither on the base model original behaviour would return `null` anyway.
- For methods I had to catch a `BadMethodCallException` to be sure that called method doesn't exists on current model instance nor in Eloquent magic methods before calling the base model.

```php
public function __get($key)
{
    $x = $this->getAttribute($key);
    if (null === $x) {
        return $this->baseModel->getAttribute($key);
    }

    return $x;
}

public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    try {
        if (in_array($method, ['increment', 'decrement'])) {
            return $this->$method(...$parameters);
        }

        if ($resolver = (static::$relationResolvers[get_class($this)][$method] ?? null)) {
            return $resolver($this);
        }

        return $this->forwardCallTo($this->newQuery(), $method, $parameters);
    } catch (\BadMethodCallException $e) {
        return $this->forwardCallTo($this->baseModel, $method, $parameters);
    }
}
```

I remark that this solution is tied to my personal use case, so probably can be improved to be more general and became a reusable trait.